# Using volley to POST multipart request

Tags: android, android-volley, flask-restful

I have a python (flask-restful) endpoint with below swagger definition:

parameters:

```
- name: tmp_no
      in: formData
      type: integer
      required: true
      description: |
        Blah blah blah

- name: mod_no
      in: formData
      type: integer 
      required: true
      description:  |
        Blah blah blah

- name: img_file
      in: formData
      type: file
      required: true
      description: |
        Blah blah blah

- name: txt_file
      in: formData
      type: file
      required: true
      description: |
        Blah blah blah
```

I am trying to call this endpoint from my android app using VolleyPlus.

```
 SimpleMultiPartRequest smr = new SimpleMultiPartRequest(Request.Method.POST, BASE_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.v("Response", response);
                                   
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            });

    try {
        smr.addFile("img_file", currentPicFile.getAbsolutePath());
        smr.addFile("txt_file", currentTxtFile.getAbsolutePath());
        smr.addMultipartParam("tmp_no", "multipart/form-data", Integer.toString(index));
        smr.addMultipartParam("mod_no", "multipart/form-data", Integer.toString(mod));
        smr.setFixedStreamingMode(true);

        VolleyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(smr);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
```

On the server, I am receiving 400:

> error: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

I guess I am not structuring my request body correctly. Any idea where I could be going wrong?